# How to build Revit Apps without restarting

Tags: revit, revit-api

Does anyone know how to build a .NET C# Revit application without having to restart Revit every time?  This applies to REVIT MEP 2013.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the relevant posts by Jeremy Tammik are:

- [Reload Add-in for Debug Without Restart](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/12/reload-add-in-for-debug-without-restart.html)
- [Debugging an Add-in Without Restarting Revit](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/05/debugging-an-add-in-without-restarting-revit.html)

Even though I happen to be the developer of the [RevitPythonShell](http://code.google.com/p/revitpythonshell/) mentioned in the post, I suggest you try the AddIn manager first - this will let you reload your addin at runtime and models most closely what you are trying to achieve.

If you want to add some tests to your pluging, then try to use the Python (RevitPythonShell) or Ruby shells mentioned in the article to create scripts that

1. load your plugin
2. exercise some functionality in your plugin

Or just use the shells to try out some API calls to see if they do what you think, before putting them in your C# code!